# Is it possible to set user properties of Azure service bus message in Java?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I would like to add some filters on my Azure service bus topic subscriptions, and filters can only be based on system properties/ user properties rather than the actual payload of message. When I looked through the documentation of Azure [serviceBusMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage?view=azure-java-stable), I found they didn't provide any methods to set user properties.

My question is that is it possible to set the user properties when using `serviceBusMessage` in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Filters on system properties can be set with format as `sys.<system-property-name>` below are few samples:

```
- sys.Label LIKE ‘%Bus%’ ##Filters all messages that contains the string “Bus” in the Label of the BrokeredMessage object.
- user.Country = ‘Austria’ ##same as: Country = ‘Austria’
- sys.Size < 1000
- sys.ForcePersistence = false
- sys.Size < 100 * sys.SequenceNumber
```

Topic Subscriptions support Rules to filter the messages. Based on the rule created in the Subscription, messages will fall into the appropriate Subscription.

Also refer this [documentation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/how-to-set-and-get-custom-properties-of-a-service-bus-message-in/ba-p/2646959) to know about How to Set and Get Custom Properties of a Service Bus Message in Logic App

And check [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) for filters and actions